# Need help in a SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining between 3 tables and getting the wrong result. The goal is to list ALL the restaurants in the restaurants table and display the rating for any restaurant if the rating exists, otherwise display null, and only for ratings for burger.

**This is the SQL:**

```
    SELECT r.RestaurantID, RestaurantName, cr.Rating FROM Restaurant r
      LEFT JOIN CustRating cr ON cr.RestaurantID = r.RestaurantID
      LEFT JOIN FoodType ft ON ft.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID AND 
        ft.FoodTypeName = 'Burger'
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

However 'Cafe C' should have Rating = null because I only want to display ratings for Burgers. What's the proper SQL?

**The SQL Statements to create the tables and populate with data:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Restaurant](
    [RestaurantID] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [RestaurantName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL

)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FoodType](
    [FoodTypeID] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [FoodTypeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL

)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustRating](
    [RestaurantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FoodTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Rating] [smallint] NOT NULL
 ) 

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustRating]([RestaurantID], [FoodTypeID], [Rating])
SELECT 2, 1, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 2
COMMIT;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FoodType]([FoodTypeID], [FoodTypeName])
SELECT 1, N'Burger' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'Taco'
COMMIT;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Restaurant]([RestaurantID], [RestaurantName])
SELECT 1, N'Cafe A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'Cafe B' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, N'Cafe C'
COMMIT;
GO
```

Comment: +1 for SQL DDL :) But your sample data in your SQL DML doesn't seem to match your picture.

Comment: @onedaywhen I recreated the tables and ran the query and I get the same result. Maybe you can explain further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT              
                    Restaurant.*
                    ,CASE  WHEN FoodType.FoodTypeID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CustRating.Rating END AS Rating

 FROM               Restaurant Restaurant
 LEFT OUTER JOIN    CustRating CustRating 
 ON                 Restaurant.RestaurantID =   CustRating.RestaurantID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN    FoodType FoodType 
 ON                 FoodType.FoodTypeID = CustRating.FoodTypeID
 AND                FoodType.FoodTypeName = 'Burger'
```

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
SELECT r.RestaurantID, RestaurantName, T.Rating 
FROM Restaurant r
  LEFT JOIN (
    select cr.RestaurantID, cr.Rating 
    from FoodType f 
    inner join CustRating cr on f.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID
    where f.FoodTypeName = 'Burger'
  ) T on r.RestaurantID = t.RestaurantID
```

Comment: +1 for the right answer, but the query plan involve Hash join - which is performance killer, using flat joins is 4 times faster here

Comment: @OlegDok: can you explain where is the hash join ? I suppose its between the subquery result (T) and the restaurant table ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  r.RestaurantID, 
  RestaurantName, 
  CASE WHEN ft.FoodTypeID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE cr.Rating END Rating
FROM Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN CustRating cr ON cr.RestaurantID = r.RestaurantID
LEFT JOIN FoodType ft ON ft.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID AND 
ft.FoodTypeName = 'Burger'
```

Comment: Note the tables lack keys (hint: you need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work; You need to remove the "TACO"-row before actually join with it

```
SELECT r.RestaurantID, RestaurantName, crft.Rating 
   FROM Restaurant r    
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT cr.RestaurantID, cr.Rating
                     FROM CustRating cr JOIN FoodType ft  
                       ON ft.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID 
                    WHERE ft.FoodTypeName = 'Burger' ) as crft 
        ON crft.RestaurantID = r.RestaurantID
```

Maybe the Syntax is not completely right because I have no SQL-Server to test it, but the idea should be this, and like this it works perfektly on PostgreSQL

```
SELECT "r"."RestaurantID", "RestaurantName", "crft"."Rating" 
   FROM "Restaurant" r    
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                     FROM "CustRating" cr JOIN "FoodType" ft  
                       ON "ft"."FoodTypeID" = "cr"."FoodTypeID"
                    WHERE "ft"."FoodTypeName" = 'Burger' ) as crft 
        ON "crft"."RestaurantID" = "r"."RestaurantID"
```

Comment: Your right! I had the right explanation, but written the SQL to fast... Sorry for that

Comment: To be onest... Yes, I ran it, and it produces the desired result (As I said, not on Postgres, however, the principle is that)

Comment: The error is here - LEFT JOIN (SELECT * - you need to specify the aliases for two FoodTypeID fields, so the query woun't even compile in mssql

Comment: That's intresting. PostgreSql doesn't care about that. As said already before, I'm running it there and got the real result

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems writing an outer join so here's An alternative approach that avoids them (and the null value, which outer join is expressly designed to return :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.RestaurantID, r.RestaurantName, 
       N'Burger' AS FoodTypeName, cr.Rating
  FROM dbo.Restaurant r
       JOIN dbo.CustRating cr 
          ON r.RestaurantID = cr.RestaurantID
       JOIN dbo.FoodType ft
          ON ft.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID
             AND ft.FoodTypeName = N'Burger'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT r.RestaurantID, r.RestaurantName, 
       N'Burger' AS FoodTypeName, -1 AS Rating
  FROM dbo.Restaurant r
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM dbo.CustRating cr 
                          JOIN dbo.FoodType ft
                             ON ft.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID
                                AND ft.FoodTypeName = N'Burger'
                    WHERE r.RestaurantID = cr.RestaurantID
                   );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
  LEFT JOIN FoodType ft ON ft.FoodTypeID = cr.FoodTypeID WHERE 
    ft.FoodTypeID=1
```

Think could helps.

Comment: Wrong! Cafe C is simply thrown out of list